# How can I connect to YouTube API without Auth?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api

Reading the [official documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) I found this code :

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = 
  new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", clientID, developerKey);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
```

but it says `If you do not specify authentication information when creating the YouTubeRequestSettings object, then you will only be able to use the YouTubeRequest object to perform operations that do not require authentication.`

I don't mind about Authentication, but if I try :

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = 
  new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app");
```

still waiting for a developerKey, so it doesnt works.

How can I create that object without auth? Are there any methods to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried...

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = 
  new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app","","");
```

The strings in the constructor aren't nullable/optional, so you aren't instantiating it right

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt works. I see that a developer key is needed! I really don't like this behaviour....